# Emitting JSON with optional arguments (Google API)

Tags: json, android-pay

I'm writing a JSON emitter for a Google API.  The API documentation says that some fields are "optional".  How am I supposed to interpret that?  I've looked at json.org's language specification and it doesn't say.  Google's docs are not clear on the subject either.

For example, consider the "sellerData" field in the following:

```
{ 
  "iss" : "1337133713371337",
  "aud" : "Google"
  "typ" : "google/payments/inapp/item/v1",
  "exp" : "1309988959",
  "iat" : "1409988959",
  "request" :{
    "name" : "Piece of Cake",
    "description" : "Virtual chocolate cake to fill your virtual tummy",
    "price" : "10.50",
    "currencyCode" : "USD",
    "sellerData" : "user_id:1224245,offer_code:3098576987,affiliate:aksdfbovu9j"
  }
}
```

If I didn't have any "sellerData" to send, should I just send "sellerData": Null or just not put the field in at all?  The former would make my emitter code much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Optional fields can be completely omitted.

If you do not need "sellerData", do not add it to the JSON.

Once you set up a merchant sandbox account, the online documentation has a [JWT generation](https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/inapp/merchant/demo.html?pli=1) tool that let's you experiment with setting various field values.

You can also double check your JWT creation with the [JWT Decoder](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/jwtdecoder) tool.